# Oracle Multiple Insert with RowID causes Error

Tags: php, oracle, rowid

got a little problem and maybe you have a solution for me..

I have a script in PHP where I upload some data + image from an formular. Image and data is doing fine for the first table, but when I want to use the rowid from the first query for the second query, there will be the following error:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 25, column 44: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ROWID": invalid identifier ORA-06550: line 24, column 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\mmdb\test\includes\dbfuncs.inc on line 67
```

The query part looks like this:

```
DECLARE
        obj ORDSYS.$type;
        iblob BLOB;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO $table (w_id, form, beschreibung, bildsignatur, symbol, muster, teilungen, z_id, i_id, bildpfad, $column, titel)
        VALUES ({$table}_seq.nextval, '" . $inputData['shape'] . "', '" . $inputData['description'] . "', ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature.init(), '" . $inputData['symbol'] . "', '" . $inputData['pattern'] . "', '" . $inputData['divide'] . "', '" . $inputData['designer'] . "', '" . $inputData['institution'] . "', '" . $targetFile . "', ordsys.$type.init(), '" . $inputData['title'] . "')
        RETURNING ROWID INTO :rid;

        SELECT $column INTO obj FROM $table
        WHERE ROWID = :rid FOR UPDATE;

        iblob := obj.source.localData;
        :extblob := iblob;

        UPDATE $table SET $column = obj WHERE ROWID = :rid;

        FOR I IN 1.." . count($inputData['tags']) . " LOOP
            INSERT INTO W_HAT_S (w_s_id, w_id, s_name)
            VALUES (I, :rid, '" . $inputData['tags'][0] . "');
        END LOOP;
    END;";
$blob = OCINewDescriptor ($db, OCI_D_LOB);
$rowid = OCINewDescriptor($db, OCI_D_ROWID);

$sql = strtr ($sql, chr(13).chr(10), " ");
$stmt = OCIParse($db, $sql);
OCIBindByName($stmt, ':extblob', $blob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
OCIBindByName($stmt, ':rid', $rowid, -1, OCI_B_ROWID);

oci_execute ($stmt, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
$blob->savefile($file);
oci_commit($db);
OCIFreeStatement ($stmt);
$blob->free();
return $rowid;
```

The error is caused by the line `VALUES (I, :rid, '" . $inputData['tags'][0] . "');` with the error message from above. When I replace the `:rid` in this line with an Integer, the whole script is working but I need it dynamically...

Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: Why do you want to store the `ROWID`? It's not a stable identifier, because there are various database management activities which can cause rows to move. You are populating a key column with a sequence - why not return and store that value?

Comment: When you select a ROWID you select into a character variable. When you then want to use the ROWID you have stored you need to use the CHARTOROWID function on it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am very new to oracle, so please be patient :D ... @APC Well I insert a new set of data and in this inserting progress I want to insert some data to another table where I need the ID from the first one. I want to do it in one step or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @BriteSponge Where should I use this function? Because if I use it in the loop, then this causes another error because its rowid and not a number and without the loop part it will insert my dataset in the database.

Comment: Your code clearly shows you inserting `:rid` - rowid -   into W_HAT_S table. That seems like permanent persistence rather than temporary referencing. So you shouldn't be using ROWID for that, you should be using the primary key from the first table

Comment: I'm not sure what other problem you mean but CHARTOROWID(:rid) would needed where you refer to :rid. However, as @APC points out you should not store it in a row in the table. The rowid can change and sometimes you can get duplicates. Best it isn't always immutable and unique.